# Spring application issues to connect to mongo db

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

Spring boot application.

MongoDb Database hosted on mongodb cloud.

Application propperties

```
#Database connection string
spring.data.mongodb.host=cluster0.mbdhj.mongodb.net
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=sample_supplies
spring.data.mongodb.username=user
spring.data.mongodb.password=[my password]
spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true
```

Error

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: No such host is known (cluster0.mbdhj.mongodb.net)
```

If I use the same host/port/user/password combination with MongoDb Compass, i can connect without issues.

If I use a cluster connection like this

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=cluster0-shard-00-02.mbdhj.mongodb.net
```

the application throws error

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
```

I've opened the firewall, to accept any connection.

Analitics show some actions, but i still get error in Spring.

I was just following a single youtube tutorial. In their example this didn't cause any issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Should I write a class that connects via Java to the database?

Comment: Can you please check with connecting using IP address?

Comment: @prostýčlověk i've switched to a localhost mongo db instance. the mongo cloud does not allow any request from my application. the current issue is, that the local mongo sends empty responses, but that is an issue for a different thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo cloud instances do not allow direct connection while debugging